# Show address bar on.net WebBrowser

Tags: .net

I'm 99% sure there was a way to show an address bar (and also a status bar with a loading progress bar) in .net's [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d67hf8a.aspx) control, instead of writing one myself. I think it was something with the underlying control, not a very "official" way. I just can't remember how I did it.

Comment: Hmmm. I think it was something with IWebBrowser2. It has an AddressBar property. Not sure how to access the IWebBrowser2 from the WebBrowser though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code on the [MSDN docs page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) discusses how to add an address bar for use with the WebBrowser control.

There is also the article [How to: Add Web Browser Capabilities to a Windows Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8ys666.aspx)